# Text styled with CSS does not appear white

Tags: css, javafx

I have got this code:

```
private void createAndAddCommonInformationSection(){
    Text text = new Text("CommonText");
    gridPane.add(header);
}
```

The should appear in white color, so I have a CCS-file as follows:

```
.root {
-fx-base: rgb(50, 50, 50);
-fx-background: rgb(50, 50, 50);
-fx-control-inner-background:  rgb(50, 50, 50);
}

.tab {
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to top, -fx-base, derive(-fx-base,30%));
}

.menu-bar {
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, -fx-base, derive(-fx-base,30%));
}

.tool-bar:horizontal {
-fx-background-color:
linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-base,+50%), derive(-fx-base,-40%), derive(-fx-base,-20%));
}

.button {
-fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.button:hover {
-fx-background-color: -fx-shadow-highlight-color, -fx-outer-border, -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color;
-fx-color: -fx-hover-base;
}

.table-view {
-fx-table-cell-border-color:derive(-fx-base,+10%);
-fx-table-header-border-color:derive(-fx-base,+20%);
}

.split-pane:horizontal > * > .split-pane-divider {
-fx-border-color: transparent -fx-base transparent -fx-base;
-fx-background-color: transparent, derive(-fx-base,20%);
-fx-background-insets: 0, 0 1 0 1;
}

.my-gridpane {
-fx-background-color: radial-gradient(radius 100%, derive(-fx-base,20%), derive(-fx-base,-20%));
}

.separator-label {
-fx-text-fill: orange;
}

.text{
-fx-text-fill: white;
}
```

Everythin is working fine with the CSS-file, except the the color of the text in my code snippet does not appear in the expected color.

I have already tried

```
-fx-fill: white;
```

and

```
-fx-fill-text: white;
```

but nothing helps.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Rounin guessing that's something to do with the `javafx` in the question.

Comment: @Rounin Read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#intronaming): "Naming conventions have been established for deriving CSS style‑class names from JavaFX class names, and for deriving CSS property names from JavaFX variable names. ... The convention for mapping JavaFX variable names to CSS property names is similar, with the addition of the '-fx-' prefix."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#text), `Text` nodes have no default style class. so you need

```
text.getStyleClass().add("text");
```

in order for the text node to match the CSS selector. Then

```css
.text {
    -fx-fill: white ;
}
```

will work.

Typically you would use a `Label` along with the `fx-text-fill` property if you want to style it with CSS, though adding a style class manually to a `Text` node should work.

Comment: I hoped to avoid changing everything to labels (it is an existing code - not my own). For some reason this code does not use any labels at all. :(

Comment: @Marco That sounds like fun... I'll let you evaluate whether it's easier to add a bunch of style classes by hand, or change all the `Text` instances to `Label`s...

Comment: What a mess! There is some styling done within the code itself, and some styling done by CSS. I think I will shut down Eclipse for today and rethink this to find a proper solution. Whoever did this had no clue of what he was doing, I suppose.